# I cannot get the right value (EBS ORACLE) - addresses

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

I've been trying without success to obtain the right value (not the id one)

Take a look: everytime that i execute my query in order to obtain **ALL** the addesses for an specific account number (SHIP_TO, BILL_TO and other addresses) i got these columns (DO NOTE THAT I CANNOT UPLOAD IMAGES YET)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHY2w.jpg)

This is my query:

```
SELECT
 hca.account_number Client_account_number
,'Contact' firstname
,Hp.Party_Name  lastname
, hl.address1 Street
, 0  StreetNumber
,hl.country Country_ID
, hl.city City
, (Select Geography_Name From Hz_Geographies
   Where Geography_Type = 'PROVINCE'
   And Geography_Code = hl.province) Region
, hl.postal_code postcode
 , CASE   
     WHEN Primary_Phone_Area_Code IS NULL  THEN NULL
      ELSE
        Hp.Primary_Phone_Country_Code || ' - ' || Primary_Phone_Area_Code || ' - ' || Primary_Phone_Number
     END telephone
,'2' Type_Id
,SUBSTR(Hcsa.Orig_System_Reference,4,20) orig_system_ref
,Hcsa.Orig_System_Reference
,hl.location_id
FROM hz_parties hp
, hz_party_sites hps
, hz_locations hl
, hz_cust_accounts_all hca
, hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcsa
, hz_cust_site_uses_all hcsu
WHERE hp.party_id = hps.party_id
AND hps.location_id = hl.location_id
AND hp.party_id = hca.party_id
AND hcsa.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
AND hcsu.cust_acct_site_id = hcsa.cust_acct_site_id
AND hca.cust_account_id = hcsa.cust_account_id
AND hca.account_number in ('account_number')
AND NVL (hcsu.status, 'A') = 'A'
AND hp.status = 'A'
AND hcsa.status = 'A'
order by orig_system_ref
;
```

Last column is returning the id for the "original" value, not the correct one.

Could you please help me to understand what is going on here? How could i modify my query in order to obtain the value that i want?

PS:i am connecting to an oracle databse (11g)

Comment: share sample data and output not image please

Comment: Thank you for replying!.
What do you mean by "sample data"?What should i give you?

Comment: that means your table samples data'

Comment: So, you want an excel file with all the results?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk here you can create your table ans share this with others which helps to get solution]

Comment: But.. i dont know how to create those tables (there are several data and "personal" information)